# How does the new geometry node Deform Curve on Surface work?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Does anybody have information about the new *Deform Curve on Surface* node? How does it work?

[image]

Comment: What is the version? Is it actually ready?

Comment: of course it is the newest 3.4 alpha....‍♂️

Comment: Try searching in resent commits https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/shortlog

Comment: the node is used to attach the new hair curves of Blender 3.3 to a surface (e.g. the head or body).

Comment: Thank you Blunder! I will accept and upvote that as an answer if you want to…?

Comment: Why it has 0 search results in Google? Where is a commit?

Comment: that's why i asked...google didn't showed me anything....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *Deform Curves on Surface* node is used to attach the new hair curves of Blender 3.3 to a surface, e.g. the head or body. **It is needed when the surface is deformed by a modifier such as the *Armature*, *Wave*, or the *Subdivision Surface* modifier.**

To work properly, **the surface object must be UV unwrapped and there must be no overlapping UV islands.** Also, it needs the curve attribute *surface_uv_coordinate*. If there is something wrong you get a warning/error message in the status bar and it won't work properly.

When you add a *Curve > Empty Hair* object to a selected object, Blender creates a *Curve* object, automatically makes it a child of the selected object, and adds a *Geometry Nodes* modifier with only a single *Deform Curves on Surface* node to the new curve object.

**Example** of the default cube with a level 3 *Subdivision Surface* modifier and hair curves:

[image: test 1]

Disabled the *Geometry Nodes* modifier with the *Deform Cuves on Surface* node and the hair follows the original mesh of the default cube:

[image: test 2]

For more info, see:

- [Blender.Today LIVE #199](https://youtu.be/lG5dNhabwBk?t=626)
- [D14864 Curves: Deform curves based on surface node.](https://developer.blender.org/D14864)