Particle Hair not rendering correctly in Cycles
I'm trying to add hair to my beveled geometry, which I imported as an SVG from Illustrator to create an outline for my text.
When I add a mesh cube and apply particle hair, it renders fine, but the particles don't render properly on my imported geometry. Any help would be appreciated.

I'm a beginner and followed some YouTube tutorials.

Have you UV unwrapped the "Ooft!" surface object? Hair curves need a UV map and a Deform Curves on Surface node (Geometry Nodes); example: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/270962/107598. Additionally, you must define the surface object in the curve object's settings, and you should check the Add Rest Position checkbox of the surface object. Finally, the curve object should be a child of the surface object.
